# Mule configuration exception

Tags: mule, drools, anypoint-studio

I am using Mule and trying to apply dynamic rules engine using Drools. Please find the configuration below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:bpm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm"
    xmlns:script="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" 
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd 
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.2/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm/3.2/mule-bpm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd">

    <bpm:drools />
    <flow name="muledroolFlow">
        <composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="VM"/>
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="10.208.17.142" port="9092" path="example" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </composite-source>
        <script:component doc:name="Script">
            <script:script engine="groovy">
                <![CDATA[
                    import java.util.Random
                    import com.mulesoft.mule.droolsjpmexample.Order

                    Random generator = new Random();
                    def order = new Order();
                    int idx=generator.nextInt(4);
                    order.setMerchant("Target");
                    double weight=generator.nextDouble()*200.0;
                    order.setWeight(weight);
                    return order;
                ]]>
            </script:script>
        </script:component>

        <bpm:rules rulesDefinition="E:/mule_workspace/muledrool/src/main/app/routingRules.drl" />
        <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="message.getPayload().getObject()" doc:name="Expression"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

My routingRules.drl is as follows

```
global org.mule.module.bpm.MessageService mule;

import com.mulesoft.mule.droolsjpmexample.Order

dialect "java"

#declare Order
#   @role(event)
#end

rule "Select WareHouse A"
    #lock-on-active
when
    order:Order(weight>50)
then
    order.setDestination("WAREHOUSE_A");
    #modify($order){setDestination("WAREHOUSE_A")}
end

rule "Select WareHouse B"
    #lock-on-active
when
    order:Order(weight<=50)
then
    order.setDestination("WAREHOUSE_B");
#   modify($order){setDestination("WAREHOUSE_B")}
end
```

On deploying this application, am getting the below exception, please assist me in fixing the same.

```
INFO  2016-03-10 13:01:50,038 [main] org.mule.util.monitor.ExpiryMonitor: disposing monitor
ERROR 2016-03-10 13:01:50,069 [main] org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry: Failed to shut down registry cleanly: org.mule.Registry.Spring
org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "dispose" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@aff120
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:248) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextDisposePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextDisposePhase.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistryLifecycleManager$SpringContextDisposePhase.applyLifecycle(SpringRegistryLifecycleManager.java:141) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.dispose(AbstractRegistry.java:68) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker$2.onTransition(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker$2.onTransition(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:64) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryBrokerLifecycleManager.fireDisposePhase(RegistryBrokerLifecycleManager.java:82) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.dispose(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:137) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.dispose(DefaultMuleContext.java:345) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.doDispose(TransactionalQueueManager.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.queue.AbstractQueueManager.dispose(AbstractQueueManager.java:109) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager.dispose(DelegateQueueManager.java:83) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 35 more
INFO  2016-03-10 13:01:50,070 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Closing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@d84149: startup date [Thu Mar 10 13:01:45 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
ERROR 2016-03-10 13:01:50,093 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.bpm.Rules.initialise(Rules.java:90) ~[mule-module-bpm-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.bpm.RulesComponent.doInitialise(RulesComponent.java:69) ~[mule-module-bpm-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(ComponentLifecycleManager.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.initialise(AbstractComponent.java:221) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.doInitialise(Flow.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:97) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
INFO  2016-03-10 13:01:50,094 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'muledrool' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2016-03-10 13:01:50,128 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'muledrool', see below         +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: NullPointerException: 
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:197) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.3.jar:?]
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: null (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: null (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: null
    at org.mule.module.bpm.Rules.initialise(Rules.java:98) ~[mule-module-bpm-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.bpm.RulesComponent.doInitialise(RulesComponent.java:69) ~[mule-module-bpm-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(ComponentLifecycleManager.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.initialise(AbstractComponent.java:221) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.doInitialise(Flow.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:97) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.bpm.Rules.initialise(Rules.java:90) ~[mule-module-bpm-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.bpm.RulesComponent.doInitialise(RulesComponent.java:69) ~[mule-module-bpm-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1.onTransition(AbstractComponent.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.ComponentLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(ComponentLifecycleManager.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.initialise(AbstractComponent.java:221) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:317) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:241) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.Flow.doInitialise(Flow.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:97) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[?:1.7.0_15]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the above code,

1. You should change the `dialect "java"` in drools file to `dialect "mvel"`
2. Add the below code

```
   <bpm:rules rulesDefinition="E:/mule_workspace/muledrool/src/main/app/routingRules.drl" initialFacts-ref="order1" />
```